# How to resolve "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.appendChild]" error

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a json object returned from ajax and when i alert it, it is displayed correctly and i try to add those into a unordered list and add that to a place holder div, but throws the above error..

```
function handleResponse() {
  if(httpa.readyState == 4){
  var response = httpa.responseText;
    //alert(response);
    if(response!='empty')
    {
      //alert(response);
      eval("prod="+response);
      var len = prod.length;
      var st = "<ul>";
      for(var cnt=0;cnt<len;cnt++)
      {
        st = st + "<li onclick='set("+prod[cnt].id+")'>"+prod[cnt].name+"</li>";  
      }      
      st = st + "</ul>";
      }
      var tt = document.getElementById('holder1');
      tt.appendChild(st); // i even tried **tt.appendChild(eval(st));**
      tt.style.display = 'block';  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

- `eval("prod="+response);` - don't do that. It's creates a global 'prod' variable, can execute arbitrary code, prevents the JS engine from speeding up your code, and generally is considered a bad coding practice.

  - Use a JSON parser instead (either from [json.org](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js) or helpers from your favorite library).
- `tt.appendChild(st); // i even tried **tt.appendChild(eval(st));**` - `appendChild` takes a DOM node; `st` is a string and `eval(st)` evaluates `st` assuming it contains JavaScript code (so running it on XML will result in a syntax error, unless you're using [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML), which still wouldn't create an object suitable for use with `appendChild`).

  - You should either parse the HTML code you've built (via `innerHTML`, `createDocumentFragment`, or -- again -- using a helper from your favorite JS library)
- Finally, if you do this a lot, consider [using templates instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202289/how-to-build-the-dom-using-javascript-and-templates).

Comment: now i had cleared that using a innerHTML Property and now it works.. And as far as the display i added an empty <a> after <li>  and now my items are working but little bit in an awkward manner.. Its displayed below the table-cell .. If i want a item to be displayed as an separate element from the table/parent , how could i do.. By the way i'm looking ar using templates.. so have to move my code a bit

Comment: it's not really clear what you mean. Could you post a small test page demonstrating the problem somewhere like http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Holicreature: I meant a somewhat working page - here, I fixed it up for you: http://jsbin.com/odale3/3/edit (you missed a <body> tag and had an extra </script> in the JavaScript section). Now how do I see the problem? You have to replace XMLHttpRequest with code feeding a constant string to the code that builds the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
tt.innerHTML += st;
```

As `st` is a string, not a DOM element.

Comment: that doesn't work. I can see the code when i view the source... 
But what may be the problem. the rendered code is like this.
<tr><td><input name="pname1" onkeyup="showlist(this.value);" type="text"><div style="display: block; z-index: 100;" id="holder1"><ul><li onclick="set(1)">Pepsodent 100g</li><li onclick="set(2)">Pepsodent 40g</li><li onclick="set(3)">Pepsodent brush</li></ul></div></td><td><input name="price1" class="rjust" type="text"></td><td><input name="quan1" class="rjust" onkeyup="settotal(1)" type="text"></td><td><input name="tprice1" class="rjust" type="text"></td></tr>

Comment: What's wrong with the rendered code.  That looks like what you wanted.

Comment: Don't use "innerHTML +="!

It's inefficient and resets the state of the DOM that can't be serialized (e.g. attached event listeners), since it first serializes the content of an element, appends the string to the serialization, parses the new string, and replaces current children of an element with the new content.

Comment: Nothing is  wrong with the rendered code but there is nothing to see..
I can't see a div with list items... It is visible only when i view source..