# Are/were there any browsers that allow control flow constructs to survive script tags?

Tags: php, javascript, browser, curly-braces

Whereas, in PHP, it's possible to:

```
<?PHP if($foo) { ?>
<strong>only appears if $foo is true.</strong>
<?PHP } else { ?>
<em>only appears if $foo is false.</em>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Can one, in Javascript, open a pair of curlies in one script tag that get closed in another?

Comment: I don't think so. php script tags are fundamentally different from html script tags. PHP was designed to work this way, it's a templating language, after all.

Comment: Nope. Unlike the `<?php` in PHP, the `script` tags are not part of the the language (JS). The script tags are a way to embed JS into HTML. And since HTML does not know anything about JS and vice versa, there is no connection between `script` tags. PHP files are fully processed by the interpreter, but HTML files are processed by some HTML parser who does not know about JavaScript. Then each `script` tag is interpreted individually (at least syntax-wise, `script` tags still share the same scope).

Comment: Felix, thanks, but why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: **No**.

The long answer is javascript scripts are compiled and executed at the closing of the script tag (not when the document has finished loading) which means that any incomplete code is and has always been treated as a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to use templates within JavaScript, you can look at libraries like [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/). I also think this question is similar to what you're asking: [How to build the DOM using javascript and templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202289/how-to-build-the-dom-using-javascript-and-templates)