# javascript templating with data bindings

Tags: javascript, html

I've been playing around with a few js templating engines.  They all seem to offer fairly standard features and make generating html with JS much simpler.

I have yet to discover an engine though that offers data bindings on elements.  I'd like to be able to do something like:

1. render template with data to a particular div
2. update all attributes from that template with new data (not by overwriting all the html)

I'd like this mainly so I don't have to keep adding events etc to the generated html.  I have an app that is polling every 2 secs for new data and doing an innerHTML style update will make it very annoying as I have to repeatedly update the dom events associated with that html.

Has anyone seen this type of js template engine around?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But +1 for the idea.

Comment: > *so I don't have to keep adding events etc to the generated html*  Are you familiar with event delegation? That is, adding the event listeners once to the container div, instead of each child, and have event propagation take care of the rest?

Comment: i don't understand.  if for instance I have 5 different controls (ie links) that do 5 different things and I replace that html, I still have to individually add those 5 events again.

Comment: ah I see...  thx for the heads up!  I have a feeling my event coding is about to change.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: Can you add some reference links to what you mean by 'event delegation'? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @John: sure! See this previous answer I gave with lots of juicy links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation/1688293#1688293 Note there is nothing in there about JavaScript template engines.

Answer (score 1):

There was an earlier question “[What good template language is supported in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128949/what-good-template-language-is-supported-in-javascript)”, in which @balupton mentions a [Smarty implementation in JavaScript](http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-smarty/demo/) that can apparently do this.

Comment: haven't verified this to be true yet, but a quick glance at the site and I didn't see anything about this type of functionality

Comment: You want to scroll all the way down on the demo page, and look at the “auto_update” section.