# Javascript framework for very simple single-page prototype

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks, singlepage

I am looking for a javascript framework to do a very simple single-page prototype. I just need to show a page when I click on a button, and show another one when I click on another button.

In one word, a MVC without the model and the controller, I just need to show and hide some views (this is the reason why the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810086/recommended-javascript-framework-for-single-page-applications does not apply here).

I could do it by myself, but maybe there's no need to reinvent the wheel… I saw such a tool some time ago, but I can't get it again.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript at all for this? Won't plain HTML and some `<a>` tags do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to show a page when I
>   click on a button, and show another
>   one when I click on another button.

I believe that can easily be accomplished by only using [jquery](http://jquery.com). No need for more than that(maybe one of those thousand [template libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128949/what-good-template-language-is-supported-in-javascript)). Just use [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to bind click event to button and [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load page when button has been presed.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is a pair of on click events, then I think you should consider writing it in plain *JavaScript*. Other than that, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is an excellent Library you could use, though it's *not* a framework; it will probably help you accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery/jquery ui then.  No M, No C, just showing/hiding divs and doing popups.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Microsoft jQuery Templates plugin. Every page would be presented by an individual template, and the model classes would be simple JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spark js library. It is small but quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend Angular JS framework for SPA purpose. It's light weight MVC framework. or You can check Durandal as well